# Scrapy/Python/XPath - How to extract data from within data?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy, and I've just started looking into XPath.

I'm trying to extract titles and links from html list items within a div. The following code is how I thought I'd go about doing it, (selecting the ul div, by id, then looping through the list items):

```
def parse(self, response):
    for t in response.xpath('//*[@id="categories"]/ul'):
        for x in t.xpath('//li'):
            item = TgmItem()
            item['title'] = x.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = x.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            yield item
```

But I received the same results as this attempt:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for x in response.xpath('//li'):
        item = TgmItem()
        item['title'] = x.xpath('a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = x.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        yield item
```

Where the exported csv file contains li data from source code top to bottom...

I'm not an expert and I've made a number of attempts, if anyone could shed some light on this it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to start your xpath expression used inside the inner loop with a dot:

```
for t in response.xpath('//*[@id="categories"]/ul'):
    for x in t.xpath('.//li'):
```

This would make it search in the scope of current element, not the whole page.

See more explanation at [Working with relative XPaths](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths).